# Compare database schema with existing slick tables

Tags: scala, slick

I am using `Scala`, `Slick` and `Postgres` to build an application. I have used `Slick code generator` to generate the slick tables.

I want to know if there is any way to validate if the database table schema and the slick table schema matches and do that for all slick tables in my application.

For example:

```
class DepartmentTable(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[Department](_tableTag, Some("base"), "Department") {
    val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("DepartmentId", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    val name: Rep[String] = column[String]("Name", O.Length(50,varying=true))
    val shortCode: Rep[String] = column[String]("ShortCode", O.Length(50,varying=true))
    def * = ???
    def ? = ???
}
```

I changed the database table, say add a column `parentDepartmentId` to the table and then added the same to the Slick table. Many a times, there have been issues that the alter scripts are not run on the test database and hence we will be getting some run time exceptions.

To avoid such issues, I was trying to implement something to check if the slick table matches with actual postgres table. Is it achievable ?

I tried with reflection, but not able to get all the details from the slick table. eg: actual column name

```
Slick Version : 3.0
```

**What I am trying to achieve?**

On startup of the application, I want to compare the database schema with the slick schema.

**My plan:**

1. Get all the TableQuery / Slick Tables from my application
2. Get the actual database schema using the Slick Meta
3. Compare slick tablequery structure with the actual db

Now, as Maxim suggested, I can create a registry and add each table to the registry. I just want to check if there is any other way. The reason is that if I or someone else accidentally removed adding a couple of table query to the registry, the check on that table will not be done. I am just trying to be more safer, but not sure if any such method exist.

Comment: Please make your question crystal clear by removing confusion between Slick's `Table` **class**, which describes the **structure of a table**, and **instances** of Slick's `TableQuery` class, which represent the actual database **tables** in Slick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can detect if for a given Slick table the number, names and SQL types of all columns in the database schema that is supposed to correspond with the table equal the number, names and SQL types of columns in the Slick table description of the table

```
def ?[AT <: AbstractTable[_]](tableQuery: profile.api.TableQuery[AT])
                             (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
  val table = tableQuery.baseTableRow.create_*.map(c =>
    (c.name, profile.jdbcTypeFor(c.tpe).sqlType)).toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
  MTable.getTables(tableQuery.baseTableRow.tableName).headOption.map(
    _.map{_.getColumns.map(
      _.sortBy(_.name).map(c => (c.name, c.sqlType)) == table
    )}
  ) flatMap (_.head)
}
```

You can also detect whether indexes, primary and foreign keys are identical to some extent. For that you can correspondingly combine

```
tableQuery.baseTableRow.indexes    
tableQuery.baseTableRow.primaryKeys
tableQuery.baseTableRow.foreignKeys
```

with the following methods of MTable

```
getIndexInfo    
getPrimaryKeys
getImportedKeys
```

as I did with `tableQuery.baseTableRow.create_*` and `getColumns` in the excerpt.

Now having this method you can easily check all the tables you have in your code. The only really easy question is how to get their list. To say the truth, I do not even understand how it can be a problem, as it is just a matter of keeping a centralized registry where you can enlist a table each time it is created in **your** code and which you can query for the objects stored. Let's say you have such `registry` with the methods `enlistTable` and `listTables` then your workflow will look something like

```
val departmentTable = TableQuery[DepartmentTable]
regsitry.enlistTable(departmentTable)
...
val someTable = TableQuery[SomeTableStructureClass]
regsitry.enlistTable(someTable)   
...
val anotherTable = TableQuery[AnotherTableStructureClass]
regsitry.enlistTable(anotherTable)   
...
for(table <- regsitry.listTables)
  db run ?(table) map ( columnsAndTypesAreIdentical => ... ) 
...
```

.

The Slick code generator you used ["generates Table classes, **corresponding TableQuery values**,..., as well as case classes for holding complete rows of values"](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/code-generation.html#overview) by default. The **corresponding TableQuery values** have exactly the form `val someTable = TableQuery[SomeTableStructureClass]`.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to get this. But the problem is that I do not know what all are the slick tables, so that I can't do TableQuery[Department]. I should be able to get that TableQuery for all the Slick tables in my application. But I am not able to do that. Tried a little bit of reflection, but still same.

Comment: Reflection? You might be kidding. It is just a matter of factoring your code so that ye olde registry/repository patterns are used.

Comment: Let's say, I have 100 slick tables in my code. How can I get the 'TableQuery[MyTable1]'  for those 100 tables dynamically.?

Comment: I don't understand you. What do you mean saying you have 100 slick tables. A table (rather a table stub) is some instance created based on your table description. E.g. your DepartmentTable is the description of the Departments table and other metastuff, TableQuery[DepartmentTable] is a surrogate of that table that you actually work with). So you have 100 references to "tables" that look like val table = TableQuery[...]. Factor your code so that registry.enlist(table) is called right after each of those vals definitions  or wherever and then proceed as I described in the answer.

Comment: You said you used the Slick code generator which ["generates Table classes, **corresponding TableQuery values**,..., as well as case classes for holding complete rows of values"](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/code-generation.html#overview) by default. Those **corresponding TableQuery values** is what I was talking about and what you have to register.

Comment: Thanks maxim, I can use the registry style. Was just checking if by any chance I can get the details without depending on the registry. (since, someone can accidentally remove or forget to add a particular table to registry)

Comment: For example instead of using just `TableQuery[SomeTable]` table creators can be forced to always call some method `createAndRegisterTable`, that adds a newly created table to the registry. That way no table will be forgotten. As all tables are created only with this method its accidental removal will only mean that some table is not created at all and there is obviously no risk anyone will be able work with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slick.meta` to achieve this. You are not saying which version of slick you are using so I am going to show an example using slick 3.0, but it should be really similar if you were using slick 2.x replacing the `DBIO` with the old `withSession` API and removing the reference to `ExecutionContext` and `Future`.

Here it is how you can print all the columns every table in the schema assuming that you have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope, that you import `YourDriver.api._` and replace the `???` with an actual `Database` instance:

```
val db: Database = ???

val tablesWithCols = for {
  tables <- slick.jdbc.meta.MTable.getTables
  withCols <- DBIO.sequence(tables.map(t => t.getColumns.map((t, _))))
} yield withCols

val printLines: DBIO[Seq[String]] = tablesWithCols.map {
  _.map {
    case (t, cs) => s"Table: ${t.name.name} - columns: ${cs.map(_.name).mkString(", ")}"
  }
}

val res: Future[Seq[String]] = db.run(printLines)

res.foreach(println)
```

Also, please not that the last `foreach` invocation is performed on a `Future` so you may want to  wait on the future to complete or (better) to chain it with relevant computations; if your program terminates without waiting/chaining you won't probably see anything from there.

Surprisingly, a somewhat more complex matter is getting the information out of the slick table definitions; the only way I found to do it is something like this:

```
TableQuery[YourTable].toNode.getDumpInfo
```

That will give you an AST-like structure that you can traverse to get out the definitions you need; the structure itself is not that pleasant to traverse but it should contain everything you need.

Another approach that you could explore to avoid this troubles could be creating a layer that wraps the generation of slick definitions and expose relevant metadata in a more accessible way; not sure if this wouldn't get you in bigger troubles though.

Comment: This way I will be able to get the actual schema details from the database. That I am already doing. However, what I do not know is how to get the Slick Tables which are already there in my code. I need to compare the MTable with the already exisitng tables in my code.

Comment: I expanded the answer adding a bit about getting data out form slick definitions, sorry if I didn't understand the question at the beginning.